# Google Apps Script : reference error getValue is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google App Script to use it in a spreadsheet:

I just want to get the value in the ID tab, cell B2

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Générer RM', 'createRM');
  menu.addToUi();
}

var responsableProjet = {};


function createRM() {
  getAdminInfo();
}

function getAdminInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  responsableProjet.sexe = getValue(sheet, 'ID!B2');
}
```

I'm having this weird error..

[image: again the same error]

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a range then, you can call "getValue" : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation + https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue
The code could be something like :

```
  responsableProjet.sexe = sheet.getRange('ID!B2').getValue();
```

to test...